# Jboss-5.1.0.GA instance is running in local, but not running in remote system?

Tags: jboss, netty, hornetq

And started a jboss-5.1.0.GA in remote istancne(192.168.2.127) with HornetQ and its running in local system.

Same URL I have run in remote system, their JBoss URL not running.

Is any port is blocking to run my instance in remote.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect to JBoss remotely, you need to start JBoss with a command line option like this: `-b 0.0.0.0`.  This tells JBoss to bind to all network adapters.  Otherwise, it'll only be accessible as localhost or 127.0.0.1.